# Issues running a procedure in SQL / Oracle

Tags: sql, database, oracle

I have used my notes / W3schools and Google and can't find the issue.  When I run  the procedure I get the following message:

> Warning Procedure created with compilation errors

I have created a Database based on a rowing club and have all tables working fine. Successfully preformed inner joins, cubes etc.

I am trying to run the following procedure:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE totalCost (boatName IN NVARCHAR2)
IS
    total NUMBER;
    boatCost NUMBER;
    numPeople NUMBER;
BEGIN
    SELECT COST INTO boatCost FROM Races WHERE winning_boat = 'IronPrice';
    SELECT boat_size INTO numPeople FROM Boat_size WHERE winning_boat = 'IronPrice';
    total:=boatCost*numPeople;
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('The total cost for this boat is '||total);
END totalCost;
/

CREATE TABLE Boats (
    Boat_Name VARCHAR (20),
    Boat_size Number (5),
    Fname VARCHAR (20),
    Riggin_Style VARCHAR (10),
    Price Number (20),
    Register_plate VARCHAR (20),
    Primary Key(Boat_Name),
    FOREIGN KEY (Register_plate) REFERENCES TRAILERS(Register_plate),
    FOREIGN KEY (Fname) REFERENCES Coaches(Fname));

CREATE TABLE RACES (
    Location VARCHAR (20),
    Style VARCHAR (20),
    Cost Number(5),
    Season VARCHAR (10),
    Winning_Club VARCHAR (20),
    Winning_Boat VARCHAR (20),
    Primary Key(Location))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at your code you select from `Boat_size` whereas the table in your script is called `Boats`.

Tip 1: move the `create ... procedure ...` after the table creation, then the objects the procedure uses will already exist.

Tip 2: Add `show errors` immediately after a `create ... procedure ...` to have SQL*Plus tell you which errors there are in the code just compiled.